# shell script for log analysis

Tags: linux, shell

I am getting the logs in a specific format on my linux server as

```
id \t IP \t login-id \t login-error Code \t attempts
```

I want to know all possible login-error codes which a user might have encountered.

The sample file is:

```
123  10.12.34.234 anshul     11 1
432  10.12.34.234 ra     11 2
342  10.12.34.234 anshul     12 1
445  10.12.34.234 yahoo  3  1
```

and the output should be:

```
anshul: 11,12
```

I have tried:

```
cat aaa | sort +2 -3 | grep anshul | awk -F"\t" {' print $4'}
```

This would print

```
11

12
```

But I want the output in the format as `anshul: 11,12`

Can we store the value in some variables and display as it is required.
Also the problem with this code is it was catch all the anshul whether it anshulg or anshuln or anshulp? Any suggestion to solve this.

I have done the sorting on login just to verify if the data I am getting is correct or not, since all the unique names would be sorted to single chunk.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{a[$3]=a[$3]","$4;next}END{for(i in a)print i,substr(a[i],2)}' <your_file>|grep anshul
```

Or you can directly use awk without a grep.

```
awk '{a[$3]=a[$3]","$4;next}END{print "anshul",substr(a["anshul"],2)}' <your_file>
```

Tested below:

```
> cat temp
123  10.12.34.234 anshul     11 1
432  10.12.34.234 ra     11 2
342  10.12.34.234 anshul     12 1
445  10.12.34.234 yahoo  3  1

> awk '{a[$3]=a[$3]","$4;next}END{for(i in a)print i,substr(a[i],2)}' temp
anshul 11,12
ra 11
yahoo 3

> awk '{a[$3]=a[$3]","$4;next}END{for(i in a)print i,substr(a[i],2)}' temp|grep anshul
anshul 11,12
> 
> awk '{a[$3]=a[$3]","$4;next}END{print "anshul",substr(a["anshul"],2)}' temp
anshul 11,12
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Simple solution, but you will get extra `,` at the end:

```
cat aaa | grep "anshul" | awk '{print $4}' | tr '\n' ','
```

output: `11,12,`

2) without extra `,`:

```
tmp=`cat aaa | grep "anshul" | awk '{print $4}' | tr '\n' ','`
echo ${tmp%?}
```

output: `11,12`

Of course you can easily convert this to a script that takes username as a parameter and output something like "user: anshul error(s): 11,12"

Comment: Both `cat` and `grep` are unnecessary: use `< aaa awk '/anshul/{print $4}`

Comment: You can get rid of `tr` as well, but this way code is more readable. Performance was not mentioned in this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
#% cat t
123  10.12.34.234 anshul     11 1
432  10.12.34.234 ra     11 2
342  10.12.34.234 anshul     12 1
445  10.12.34.234 yahoo  3  1
```

One line Perl.

```
 perl -ane 'BEGIN{$x='anshul';}push @{$X{@F[2]}}, $F[3];END{print "$x: ",join(",",@{$X{$x}}),"\n";}' < t
```

Gives:

```
anshul: 11,12
```